# Centering text inside Bulma Tile

Tags: css, bulma

Using Bulma CSS framework for Flask project, populating product data inside tiles (active links to product details) and want to have the **last tile with text "Add New" and icon below it centered vertically and horizontally**.

**I tried:**

1. adding `has-text-centered` class on a, div, h4;
2. removing content class from div;
3. removing parent link `a` tag in case it was messing up with tile
4. combinations of above;

**Notes:**

1. plus icon is centered in relation to h4. (How, why?)
2. I hunted down vertical centering answer with inline style which works: `style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-content: center; align-items: center;"`. But not included it due to possible conflicts with answer or Bulma built-ins
3. Side question: why second tile, which obviously has less content takes more vertical space?!

If that's isn't obvious I have little experience with CSS.

**HTML with links to bulma css and fontawesome**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Duck the Tiles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/57b41a2f3a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tile is-ancestor">

                <a class="tile is-4 box mx-2" href="#">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4>Product_1</h4>
                        <p><strong>Detail_1: </strong>Value_1</p>
                        <p><strong>Detail_2: </strong>Value_2</p>
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <a class="tile is-4 box mx-2" href="">
                    <div class="content has-text-centered">
                        <h4>Add New</h4>
                        <p>
                            <span class="icon is-large">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this class `m-auto` to your `<div>` (inside the second `<a>`)

[image]

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Duck the Tiles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/57b41a2f3a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tile is-ancestor">
        <a class="tile is-4 box mx-2" href="#">
          <div class="content">
            <h4>Product_1</h4>
            <p><strong>Detail_1: </strong>Value_1</p>
            <p><strong>Detail_2: </strong>Value_2</p>
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a class="tile is-4 box mx-2" href="">
          <!-- here is what I added in your code -->
          <div class="content has-text-centered m-auto">
            <h4>Add New</h4>
            <p>
              <span class="icon is-large">
                 <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

> I never used Bulba, 
> but I know CSS, so I tried to use `margin: auto;` in dev tools,
>
> and seems to work fine.  
> so then I searched on google "bulba css documentation"
>
>  and I found that margin is `m` and you can add `-auto` for making `margin: auto` :)

here the link of the documentation: https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/
[image]